# Last Value Null in PHP, but Jquery Picking up Last Row from Table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass variables to jquery for ajax from html/php.

This is the html/php:

```
<?php
    $propertyid = $data['property_id'];
    $select5 = $con->prepare("SELECT favorite_properties_id, favorite_properties_property_id FROM tbl_favorite_properties where favorite_properties_user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' AND favorite_properties_property_id='$propertyid;'");
    $select5->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $select5->execute();

    while($data5=$select5->fetch()){
        echo $data5['favorite_properties_id'];
        $favorite_properties_id = $data5['favorite_properties_id'];
    }
?>

<a href="#">
    <img class="addtofavoritebutton" pid="<?php echo $propertyid; ?>" fpid="<?php echo $favorite_properties_id;?>" src="../images/system/addtofavorite.png">
</a>
<?php echo $data['property_id']; ?>
```

This is the jquery:

```
$('.addtofavoritebutton').click(function() {    
    var property_id = $(this).attr('pid');
    var favorite_properties_id = $(this).attr('fpid');

    alert(property_id);
    alert(favorite_properties_id);      
});
```

There are two rows in the tbl_favorite_properties, table however jquery is picking up the last row for fpid, even when there is no data.  When I echo in php then the value is blank (as it should be) but in jquery it is taking the last row and repeating the value, when it can't find.  How can I get jquery to pick up the blank or null value just like php?

Comment: echo $data5['favorite_properties_id']; is giving the right value - in php but var favorite_properties_id = $(this).attr('fpid'); in jquery is repeating the last value when it should also pick up blank value.

Comment: your code is vulnerable to sql injection. use prepared statments as they are intended to use instead and consider the following lecture: https://laurent22.github.io/so-injections/

Comment: @Joshua - do I need to even prepare the select statements, or only the insert, update and delete statements

Comment: you should prepare all statements and use the `bindParam` methods of `PDOStatement` to set values on the queries. A good read is this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758185/php-mysql-injection-example You should consider reading the linked question there too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
                $propertyid = $data['property_id'];
                $select5 = $con->prepare("SELECT favorite_properties_id, favorite_properties_property_id FROM tbl_favorite_properties where favorite_properties_user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' AND favorite_properties_property_id='$propertyid;'");
                $select5->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $select5->execute();
                ?>

                <a href="#"><img class="addtofavoritebutton" pid="<?php echo $propertyid; ?>" fpid="<?php while($data5=$select5->fetch()){echo $data5['favorite_properties_id'];} ?>" src="../images/system/addtofavorite.png"></a>
```

This is working now.

Comment: It was the problem with loop only, thanks guys for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

PLease put your  tag inside loop

```
<?php
$propertyid = $data['property_id'];
$select5 = $con->prepare("SELECT favorite_properties_id, favorite_properties_property_id FROM tbl_favorite_properties where favorite_properties_user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' AND favorite_properties_property_id='$propertyid;'");
$select5->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$select5->execute();

while($data5=$select5->fetch()) {
    echo $data5['favorite_properties_id'];
    $favorite_properties_id = $data5['favorite_properties_id'];
    echo '<a href="#"><img class="addtofavoritebutton" pid="'.$propertyid.'" fpid="'.$favorite_properties_id.'" src="../images/system/addtofavorite.png"></a>';
}
?>
<?php echo $data['property_id']; ?>
```

Comment: If i do that then the image disappears

Comment: can u please explain what exactly you want?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are using `$favorite_properties_id` after finishing the while loop and variable `$favorite_properties_id` will contain the value of the last iteration of while loop.

```
<?php
    $propertyid = $data['property_id'];
    $select5 = $con->prepare("SELECT favorite_properties_id, favorite_properties_property_id FROM tbl_favorite_properties where favorite_properties_user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' AND favorite_properties_property_id='$propertyid;'");
    $select5->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $select5->execute();

    $favorite_properties_id = null;
    while($data5=$select5->fetch()){
        echo $data5['favorite_properties_id'];
        $favorite_properties_id = $data5['favorite_properties_id'];
    }
    ?>

    <a href="#"><img class="addtofavoritebutton" pid="<?php echo $propertyid; ?>" fpid="<?php echo $favorite_properties_id;?>" src="../images/system/addtofavorite.png"></a>

    <?php echo $data['property_id']; ?>
```

Comment: If i do that then the image disappears

Comment: I have edited code, You can check it now please. I think you need to reset  `$favorite_properties_id = null;` before loop